# A more understandable approach to this transformation of iris data

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So, I was following a book about machine learning. But I was confused a bit when I encountered this:

> the iris dataset marks setosa as zero, we have to change all targets
>   with the value 0 to 1, and the other values all to 0.We will also use
>   two features, petal length and petal width. These two features are the
>   third and fourth entry in each x-value.

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
binary_target = np.array([1. if x==0 else 0. for x in iris.target])
iris_2d = np.array([[x[2], x[3]] for x in iris.data])
```

The way the iteration is implemented, is very vague to me. I have never seen such an implementation. Is it a commonly used way that I dont know of? Or is there a better and a more convenient way to implement the same thing.
Thanks

Comment: List comprehension is _very_ commonly used. It is considered superior to `for` loops that could theoretically be use to achieve similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's establish what the code is doing - it is converting a
>   multi-class classification problem into a binary one (one vs rest) -
>   with the focus apparently on Setosa.
>
> That said, that is a really poor way of doing it, and I'm really
>   surprised to see it in a book about machine learning.

Note,

```
print(iris.target)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

And,

```
print(iris.data)
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
       ...
```

One naive way of converting this to a binary problem would be using a loop:

```
binary_target = []
for t in iris.target:
    if t == 0:
        binary_target.append(1.)
    else:
        binary_target.append(0.)
```

Reduce this to a single liner, a list comprehension, and you get:

```
binary_target = [1. if t == 0 else 0. for t in iris.target]
```

Again, this is a poor way of doing it.

I'd rather do this with `np.where`, keeping this in numpy space -

```
binary_target = np.where(iris.target == 0, 1, 0)
```

You may not see large differences (well, list comprehensions *do* run in C space and are fast), but numpy is completely vectorised. Again, this is likely not going to be the bottleneck of your code if you're implementing a machine learning classifier, so I wouldn't really worry much about it.

And similarly for the second one, like @DyZ mentioned, it is completely unnecessary. Just do -

```
iris_2d = iris.data[:, 2:4]
```

A simple slicing with `ndarray.__getitem__` is sufficient, and you don't even need to convert the result to an array (the slice already is an array).

---

In summary,

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
binary_target = np.where(iris.target == 0, 1, 0)
iris_2d = iris.data[:, 2:4]
```

Comment: is the usage of list comprehension a poor way or the way list comprehension is used a poor way?

Comment: @Huzo I love list comprehensions, they are fast. I just think their usage here is inappropriate.

Comment: Since the OP already accepted your answer, do you mind adding `binary_target = (iris.target==0).astype(bool)` to it?

Comment: @DyZ I can, but I see it already in your answer. I think yours is good, so why not leave it there?

Answer (score 3):

The first list comprehension creates a boolean array where `True` items correspond to the zero `iris.target`. The same can be accomplished using the native NumPy tools:

```
binary_target = iris.target.astype(bool).astype(int)
```

The second list comprehension is not necessary at all, because `iris.data` is already a NumPy array. So,

```
iris_2d = np.array([[x[2], x[3]] for x in iris.data])
```

must be:

```
iris_2d = iris.data[:,[2,3]]
```

I am surprised that a "book about machine learning" offers such a silly advice.

Comment: I see, I too am surprised to encounter such simple mistakes. Maybe the reason is that it is a Tensorflow book. So its scope of focus is more on the usage of Tensorflow, I guess..

Comment: Appreciate that somebody else (a professor!) shares the same view here!

Answer (score 1):

```
[1. if x==0 else 0. for x in iris.target]
```

This is a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  It creates a list.  It could also be done as:

```
[float(x==0) for x in iris.target]
```